# How the genome assembly be done after k-mer counting?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-assembly

As far I know, before assembly of a genome, all k-mers from read should be counted.

- But after that, how the genome assembly be done?
- Is there any other thing needed along with k-mer counts?
- How the standard value of k is determined for a particular genome assembly? or is it fixed for all kind of assembly?

I just want to know the basic concept that how this actually been done. Explanation with flow char or algorithm is much more appreciated.

I went through some similar question, but those did not help me too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing genome assembly.
The term you are probably looking for is "[De Bruijn-Graph based assembly](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~langmea/resources/lecture_notes/assembly_dbg.pdf)". Using this you can find a lot more different explanations of how it is done.

Another frequently used method is "[Overlap Layout Consensus assembly](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~langmea/resources/lecture_notes/assembly_olc.pdf)", which in fact is not based on k-mer counting.